# Compare data from 2 columns and returning results in a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which has around 400k rows. I need to find common words between `question1` and `question2` columns. I am able to print the output with a `zip` and `for` loop, however I would like to create a function to return these values. Can you please help me?

```
for a, b in zip(df.question1, df.question2):
    str1 = (set(a.lower().strip().split()))
    str2 = (set(b.lower().strip().split()))
    word_common =  (len(str1 & str2))
    word_total = len(str1) + len(str2)
    word_share = round(word_common/word_total,2)
    print(word_common,word_total,word_share)
```

This prints the output:

```
10 23 0.43
4 20 0.2
4 24 0.17
```

However, when i wrap this inside a function I get only one value (i.e. `word_common`) based on where i place `return` keyword. How can I store this output in a dataframe?

```
def find_common_words(df,strg1,strg2):
    for a, b in zip(df[strg1], df[strg2]):
        str1 = (set(a.lower().strip().split()))
        str2 = (set(b.lower().strip().split()))
        word_common =  (len(str1 & str2))
        word_total = len(str1) + len(str2)
        word_share = round(word_common/word_total,2)
        return word_common
```

Comment: You can use [apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506826/call-function-use-apply-in-python) with axis=1 to parse every row and call a function inside where you perform your desired operation.

Comment: append `word_common` to an empty list and return the list outside the for-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to return the values in a dataframe:

```
def find_common_words(df,strg1,strg2):
    stats = []
    for a, b in zip(df[strg1], df[strg2]):
        str1 = (set(a.lower().strip().split()))
        str2 = (set(b.lower().strip().split()))
        word_common =  (len(str1 & str2))
        word_total = len(str1) + len(str2)
        word_share = round(word_common/word_total,2)
        stats += [[word_common, word_total, word_share]]
    return pd.DataFrame(stats, columns=['Word Common', 'Word Total', 'Word Share'])
```

Comment: Thank you. this is what i was looking for. It worked like a charm.

Comment: I will make some minor edits to your question to make it clearer. Because if you wanted only `common_words` Catalina's answer would be more pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `return`, the process in the function is stopped and the value is returned. So after the first iteration in your loop the program is stopped, because of your return statement, and the first value of word_common is returned. You sould rather stock your values in a list.

Secondly, as you have a DataFrame you should use `apply` function in order to output your list. It will take in input a function and will apply it on each row of the DataFrame.

In the following code, the value of `word_common` will be stocked in a new column of your DataFrame, named `word_common`:

```
def parse_one_row(row):
    a = row['question1']
    b = row['question2'] 
    str1 = (set(a.lower().strip().split()))
    str2 = (set(b.lower().strip().split()))
    word_common =  (len(str1 & str2))
    word_total = len(str1) + len(str2)
    word_share = round(word_common/word_total,2)
    return (word_common, word_total, word_share)


df['word_common'] = df.apply(parse_one_row, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x[0], axis=1)
```

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) you have the official documentation

Comment: Thank you. This works too. why i need to use axis =1? i did not understand

Comment: You need `axis=1`, which means apply the function on each row, because axis is by default set to zero, and in this case it will apply on each column. Just a piece of advice: Use the apply function rather than for loops, because it is optimized and is faster. A for loop can be very long and take a lot of memory if you deal with huge datasets, in other words, a real catastrophy.

Comment: Thank you Catalina. Makes sense.

Comment: Hello Catalina, In the above code if i need to retrieve 'word_total','word_share',and 'word_common', how can i do that?  also, how can i add all of them to the dataframe?

Comment: In the function you return a tuple `(word_common, word_total, word_share)` and at a second stage you return the first element for `word common` with `x[0]` in the lambda function, `word total` as the second element with `x[1]` and so on.

Comment: Is there no way to create a df inside the function and call that?

Comment: Creating the DataFrame inside the function means creating it each time which you do not want. What I suggest in my code is to create it outside the function and at each iteration add a new column (according to what you want to do). What you suggest is bad practice.

Comment: Thank you Catalina. It was of immense help